# How to print a view in node.tpl.php only if it's not empty

Tags: 7, views, theming, nodes

Views can be printed in tpl.php files with this code:

```
<?php print views_embed_view('myview','block_1'); ?>
```

However, if that view is empty, the view block code will be printed anyway:

```
<div class="view view-myview view-id-myview view-display-id-block_1 view-dom-id-abc123..."></div>
```

Is it possible to check if the view has any results first and then print it if it does? E. g.:

```
<?php if ($view_myview,block_1): ?>
<?php print views_embed_view('myview','block_1'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check it using the below code

```
<?php 
$viewName = 'myview';
$displayid = 'block_1'; 

$view = views_get_view($viewName,$displayid);
$view->execute();
$reviewCount = count($view->result); //It will return number of results
if($reviewCount>0){
print views_embed_view($viewName,$displayid); 
}
?>
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: It works, thank you. What about performance - does this `count` slow down the query a lot?

Comment: Not that much. But its fine as long as it is working because it is the easiest way to do it.